# Why does function call go directly to return statement?

Tags: c++, integer, multiplication

I am a **BEGINNER**. I wrote a function to multiply big integers. When the function `multiplybig(string a,string b)` is called it goes directly to the return statement of the same function. I dont know where exactly the bug is. can someone please help me with this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
string multiplybig(string a,string b)
{
    string c;
    int ar1[a.length()] , ar2[b.length()] ; int ans[a.length()+b.length()]={0};

    for(int i=0 ; i<a.length(); i++){
        ar1[i]=a[i]-'0';
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i<a.length(); i++){
        ar2[i]=b[i]-'0';
    }

    int x = 0 ; int y = 0;

    for(int i=a.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
        for(int j=b.length()-1;j>=0;j--){
            ans[x]+=ar1[i]*ar2[j];
            x++;
        }
        y++; x=y;
    }

    for(int i=0,j=a.length()+b.length()-1;i<a.length()+b.length();i++,j--){
        c[i]=ans[j]+'0';
    }

    return c;
}
int main()
{
    string a( "123" );
    string b( "111" );
    cout<< multiplybig( a, b );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a typo there: `for(int i = 0 ; i<a.length(); i++){ ar2[i]=b[i]-'0'; }` -> `b.length()`? Probably you go out of bounds there.

Comment: Secondly some hints: `int ar1[a.length()]` is a VLA, which [are not part of the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), use `std::vector<int> ar1(a.length())` instead and [`using namespace std;` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @churill yeah thank you, i will edit that ( but problem exists even after correcting that)

Comment: Second problem I just spotted is `c[i]=ans[j]+'0';`. `c[i]` is out of bounds, since `c` is an empty string. Guess it's a good time to [learn how to use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: [You don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`. It is just noise here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up the comments:

### Don't use VLAs

```
int ar1[a.length()] , ar2[b.length()] ; int ans[a.length()+b.length()]={0};
```

are VLAa. Those are [not part of the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), but a compiler specific extension. The right way would be to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> ar1(a.length());
std::vector<int> ar2(b.length()); 
std::vector<int> ans(a.length() + b.length());
```

(one statement per line for good readability)

### Typo in the loop

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<a.length(); i++){
    ar2[i]=b[i]-'0';
}
```

Since you read from `b` the condition must be `i < b.length();`

### Out-of-bounds-access on `c[i]`

Before the line

```
c[i]=ans[j]+'0';
```

`c` get's never assigned anything (it's an empty string), so any access using the subscript operator is an out-of-bounds-access. Either resize it first:

```
c.resize(ans.size());
```

or use `push_back` instead:

```
c.push_back(ans[j]+'0');
```

---

The last error (that the returned value was ignored) you already fixed in your last edit. With all those changed I got the expected result

```
013653
```

Comment: HUGE THANKS!!! I did everything you said and learn something new today. Thanks but  will using dynamic array in heap instead of vector be fine ? What's the difference?

Comment: A vector is basically just a nice, shiny wrapper around a dynamic array. It can be used in just the same way, has almost 0 overhead (at least with compiler optimizations turned on) but provides many useful features. A `vector` should always be preferred over manual memory management.

Comment: No problem, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it was helpful to you :)